# how to handle html array elements in javascript and pass them to controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code in view file in `CodeIgniter`

```
<table width="62%" height="70" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="edit">   

    <?php if(count($voucher_info) > 0 ){ ?>
            <tr class="bgcolor_02">

            <td width="27%" align="center"   class="admin" >S.no</td>
            <td width="37%" align="center"   class="admin" >Voucher Type</td>
            <td width="47%" align="center"   class="admin" >Voucher Mode</td>

            <!--  <td width="41%" align="center" class="narmal">&nbsp;<strong>Actions</strong></td>-->

            </tr>
            <?php 
                $rownum = 1;    
                foreach ($voucher_info as $eachrecord){
                    $zibracolor = ($rownum%2==0)?"even":"odd";
            ?>
                    <tr align="center"  class="narmal">
                    <td height="25"><?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_id ; ?><input type="hidden" name="voucher_id[]" value="<?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_id; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input name="vouchertype[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_type; ?>" /></td>    
                    <td><select name="mode[]" >
                    <option value="paidin" <?php if($eachrecord->voucher_mode=='paidin') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Paid In</option>
                    <option value="paidout" <?php if($eachrecord->voucher_mode=='paidout') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Paid Out</option>
                    </select></td>                  
                    </tr>
            <?php   
                } 
        }                   
        else {
        echo "<tr class='bgcolor_02'>";
        echo "<td align='center'><strong>No records found</strong></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        } 
    ?>

</table>

<input id="update" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"/>
```

I want to know how to I handle `vouchertype[]` and `mode[]` in `JavaScript` and pass them to controller using `AJAX`??

This is my javascript code

```
 <script>
    $("#edit").hide(); // Hide the edit table first

    $("#update").click(function() {
            $("#edit").toggle();
            $("#shown").toggle();
            // If we are going from edit table to shown table

            if($("#shown").is(":visible")) {

                var vouchertype = $('input[name="vouchertype[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var mode= $('select[name="mode[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

                // Then add it to the shown table
         var baseurl='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/account/insert_voucher";?>';

                    $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: baseurl,
                            data: {'mode' : mode,'vouchertype':vouchertype} ,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html) {



                            }
                        });

                $(this).val("Edit");
            }
            else $(this).val("Update");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it like,

```
var vouchertype = $('input[name="vouchertype[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var mode= $('select[name="mode[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
$.ajax({
   url:'your-controller-url',
   data:{vouchertype :vouchertype,mode:mode },
   ....
});
```

You can pass it by using [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) like

```
$.ajax({
   url:'your-controller-url',
   data:$('#edit *').serialize(), // in this case all element would pass in controller
   ....
});
```

Comment: Simply by using `$this->input->post('Your element name');`

Comment: Please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447355/how-to-handle-html-array-elements-in-javascript-and-pass-them-to-controller-usin" and this is the same question. please help me out with that

Comment: In your `account` controller make a function `insert_voucher` and read `mode` like,
`function insert_voucher(){ $mode=$this->input->post('mode');...}`

Comment: Your other question linked with the same question. And if your table is toggled before ajax success callback then you should use your `toggling` code in `ajax success callback`. So that when you get the response then only your table would toggle

Comment: What changes should I make in above javascript code..I use toggle in ajax  success..but now success coming before table gets editable..

Answer (score 0):

If `Voucher_type` is an array you can not just echo it.
do a `urlencode(json_encode($Voucher_type))` and same for the mode also.